# Messages replayed after reboot in rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rabbitMQ cluster with two nodes configured to be synchronized. Each queue is mirrored and persistent.

Each time I need to reboot a node of my cluster, some old messages are replayed.

I don’t understand why because one of the two nodes is still alive and they are "normally" synchronized.

Have you any idea to help me to investigate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if you have some messages that are not acknowledged?
If you do (this would mean a consumer never acknowledges it), it could explain the behavior:

1. Message consumed but never acknowledged
2. Node reboots
3. The connections of the consumers connected to that node get closed
4. Any of the unacked messages that have been consumed in the related channel are put back in the queue

Comment: These messages are acknowledge indeed. And for more information, some of them are aged of 4 days.